# How to get an access token from ebay via OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, token

This is less a question than an answer. I figured I would want to share this with you, since I was a bit confused finding so litte about the ebay OAuth 2.0 in combination with a C# web application.

I tried starting to use the RESTsharp library, but got stuck at the point, where the body content was created. RESTsharp prefers XML or JSON, ebay want's a string with params.

So to give you all a little help if you run into the same issue, I decided to post my solution (not using RESTsharp).

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    string clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
    string clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";
    string ruName = "YOUR_RU_NAME";
```

// Redirect the request to get a request token

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var authorizationUrl =
            "https://signin.sandbox.ebay.de/authorize?" +
            "client_id=" + clientId + "&" +
            "redirect_uri=" + ruName + "&" +
            "response_type=code";

        Response.Redirect(authorizationUrl);
        return View();
    }
```

// I used Test as a method to test the result in the controller, use your apropriate method here

```
    public ActionResult Test(string code)
    {
        ViewBag.Code = code;

        // Base 64 encode client Id and client secret
        var clientString = clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
        byte[] clientEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientString);
        var credentials = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(clientEncode);

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token")
            as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, credentials);

        var codeEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);

        var body = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + codeEncoded + "&redirect_uri=" + ruName;

        // Encode the parameters as form data
        byte[] formData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
        request.ContentLength = formData.Length;

        // Send the request
        using (Stream post = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            post.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
        }

        // Pick up the response
        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        ViewBag.Response = result;

        return View();
    }
```

If you output ViewBag.Response you will see the authorization code. Have fun.

Comment: move your logic out of controllers and into models. they can then be used in libraries which in turn can then be used in other projects, be them console, web or wpf/winforms.

Comment: also new documentation: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/sell/content/selling-ig/dev-app.html which gives a clearer and concise breakdown of how to get keys and more with full explanations.

Comment: In http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/oauth-quick-ref-user-tokens.html  is some material about it.  I didn't find in your  "ActionResult Index()" scope. Did you get corect tokens without it?

Comment: @Michael Staples Were you able to get the auth token?

Comment: @Jobs yes, I get a result with this. Of course in terms of reusability I would also recommend to create seperate libraries.

Comment: What's that code parameter that you're reading from ViewBag? Where to get this from?

Comment: @Hajjat the code is the code returned from ebay to the controller. Necessarily you need to encode it and perform another call with the code returned. The ebay Authorization works in three steps:
- Register the App with a developer account
- Redirect the user to allow the app to have access
- Make a call with the returned code to get the OAuth Token

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStaples, let me try that out! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

How is your redirect url looking in sandbox? Seems like the url should be https. In this stage in dev environment and don't have server with https. How did you deal with that?

Ta

Comment: I created a certificate despite issues with browser warnings to help me out on this point.